# How to merge each two columns into one and the number of columns into half

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

Data frame df :

```
  0 1 2 3 4 A B C D E 
1 0 1 1 0 0 a b d s e     
2 0 0 1 0 0 a w d d e     
3 0 0 1 1 0 a c w d e
```

Is there any way that I can convert the data frame to the new one by merge each two columns corresponding index number and letter?

```
  0(A) 1(B) 2(C) 3(D) 4(E) 
1 0(a) 1(b) 1(d) 0(s) 0(e)     
2 0(a) 0(w) 1(d) 0(d) 0(e)   
3 0(a) 0(c) 1(w) 1(d) 0(e)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `paste0` with `mapply`:

```
DF <- read.table(text="  0 1 2 3 4 A B C D E 
1 0 1 1 0 0 a b d s e     
2 0 0 1 0 0 a w d d e     
3 0 0 1 1 0 a c w d e", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)

DF1 <- as.data.frame(mapply(function(x, y) paste0(x, "(", y, ")"), 
                            DF[, 1:5], DF[, 6:10]))
names(DF1) <- paste0(names(DF1), "(", names(DF[, 6:10]), ")")

#  0(A) 1(B) 2(C) 3(D) 4(E)
#1 0(a) 1(b) 1(d) 0(s) 0(e)
#2 0(a) 0(w) 1(d) 0(d) 0(e)
#3 0(a) 0(c) 1(w) 1(d) 0(e)
```

Comment: Nice answer. Just for generalizability, I suggest using `grep("[0-9]", colnames(DF))` instead of `1:5` and `grep("[A-Z]", colnames(DF))` instead of `6:10`.